# Review - First questions - mixed answers and questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

[First questions review page](https://superuser.com/review/first-questions?pagesize=15&filter=all) lists both answers and questions, mixed. That's annoying, as it's tempting to flag answers as "not question" and vice versa, until realizing that it's actually answer.

Why is that changed, or is it a bug?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, just put a fix in place. Will be deployed in the next day.